# how to pick a new index of an array by each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function that it includes an array of colours, and there is a button and a text tag. So after each click, the function take the current index of the array, show it in the text and add one to the index number so next time the next index will be shown.

Here is my code:

```
var mycolor = 0;

var color = function() {
    var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];    
    return list[mycolor];
    mycolor++;
};

function run(){
    $(".demo").text(color());
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brxoomvy/)

Any idea? how to fix it? currently it only shows the first index, it does not update it the variable.

Comment: i believe no code is executed after the `return` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for

```js
var mycolor = 0;
var maxcolor = 0
var color = function() {
    var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];    
    maxcolor = list.length;
    if((mycolor + 1) > maxcolor)
    {
        mycolor = 0
    }
    return list[mycolor++];
    
};

function run(){
    $(".demo").text(color());
}
```

infinite version.

Answer (score 1):

Your return is too early.  You also need to handle when mycolor is past the array length.

```
var color = function() {
    var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];    

    if (mycolor >= list.length)
       mycolor = 0;

    return list[mycolor++];
};
```

An alternative way of writing the above would be the following:

```
var color = function() {
    var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];    
    return list[mycolor++ % list.length];
};

function run(){
    $(".demo").text(color());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing post return, which guarantees the code isn't executed.

Try something like...

```
var color = function() {
    var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];    
    return list[mycolor++];
};
```

Which returns the number and then increments it. You should probably do `% list.length` to so calling beyond the length of your array will wrap the results instead of returning `undefined` (unless of course, that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var mycolor = 0;
var list = ["red", "blue", "green"]; 

var color = function() {
    return list[mycolor];
};

function run(){
    $(".demo").text(color());
    mycolor++;
    if(mycolor > 2) {
        mycolor = 0;
    }
}
```

`mycolor` isn't getting update because you incrementing it after you already have returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the only one that will work because it's the only code that includes a click event.

var mycolor = 0;
var maxcolor = 0
var color = function() {
    var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];    
    maxcolor = list.length;
    if((mycolor + 1) > maxcolor)
    {
        mycolor = 0
    }
    return list[mycolor++];

};

$(".demo").text('on', 'click', color());
```